# Line spacing in flextable R Markdown pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I am reading in a csv file and converting it to a flextable, as below. Each cell from the csv may run over several lines, depending on length. I am then outputting to pdf in R Markdown, with the code chunk option `ft.arraystretch = 0.75` to control line spacing. This used to result in the output A) i.e. 0.75 spacing 'within' a cell (as desired), but now (with no changes to the code) results in the output in B).

R Markdown YAML

```
---
title:'thesis'
documentclass: book
fontsize: 10pt
mainfont: Arial
linestretch: 1.5
output:
  pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: none
    pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "vancouver-superscript.csl" ]
    keep_tex: yes
    toc_depth: 4
---
```

Table code:

```
mutation_types <- read_csv("./R/data_management/resistance_types.csv")

mutation_types_table <- mutation_types %>% 
  regulartable() %>%
  colformat_md()

mutation_types_table <- bold(mutation_types_table,
                             part = "header")

mutation_types_table <- bold(mutation_types_table, 
                             i = c(2,5,8,11,14,17),
                             part = "body")

mutation_types_table <- fontsize(mutation_types_table, 
                                 i = NULL, 
                                 j = NULL, 
                                 size = 8, 
                                 part = "all")

mutation_types_table <- width(mutation_types_table, width = 2)

mutation_types_table
```

**A: Previous output**
[image: A]

**B: Current output**
[image: B]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What else would be helpful?